# MySQL "hand-made" partitioning

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, partitioning

I recently inherited a legacy application including a MySQL database, the centerpiece of which is a "table" which we'll call `Foo` - only it's not an actual table but a number of identical tables, named `Foo01`, `Foo02`... through `Foo31`. Records are inserted into `FooNN` when the day-of-month for that record is `NN`, this "partitioning logic" is managed at the application layer.

As a whole, `Foo` grows at a steady rate of ~100K rows per day. Total count (~3M) and row data suggest every record is deleted/historified after about a month, so size's not a big concern. Insertion happens at a roughly constant rate over time, updates are nonexistent. Queries on `Foo` happen only because of users (not so many of them) conducting manual searches, which may or may not be filtered by the "partitioning" date, and may or may not have other search parameters.

To me, this looks an awful lot like someone in the past did a hell of a premature optimization, probably combined with a spoonful of bold ignorance. But I'm no expert whatsoever, I'm just trying to understand why would someone go out of their way like this.

**Does this approach make any sense at all? i.e. would it have any advantage over MySQL's built-in partitioning (making the obvious disadvantages worth)?**

Comment: Was this db built before partitioning existed I wonder?

Comment: Don't think so @P.Salmon, MySQL has had partitioning for at least ten years, I called the app "legacy" but it's not that old.

Answer (score 2):

What you are describing is a typical SQL anti-pattern (in other words not a good design). There are many drawbacks the overcome the tiny performance gain that you might get, the most proeminent being:

- queries that need more than one table are complicated to write
- enforcing data integrity is hard (there is no primary key *across* the tables)
- maintenance of the structure is problematic (any DDL operation must be repeated over all the tables)

If your data is not too big, you can store it directly  in a single table.

If it has many rows, you can use MySQL has native partitioning.

If there are many columns and not all of them are used frequently, you can split the structure vertically and separate often-used column in another table.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @GMB, I'm aware of the cons, what I can't see are the pros, hence was my question. You mention a possible (even if tiny) performance gain, would you mind expanding on that? How would it compare to MySQL's built-in partitioning?

Comment: @willyjoker:  From a business perspective, there may be no pros.  I guess you can hammer on maintenance costs being reduced with a redesign, but the database may be good enough as is from a business perspective.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give some tentative Pros:

Assuming it would be `PARTITION BY RANGE(TO_DAYS(...))`, which is about the only useful pattern,

- Simpler queries for the user to write.  A date and a date range are very similar and hit only one table (as viewed by the user).
- When changing to/from partitioning, the indexes usually need to be redesigned.  In doing so, you either maintain, or gain, performance.
- Deleting "old" data is much faster and less invasive (than a single table) because it is a `DROP PARTITION`.  (OK, foo## is also fast and non-invasive.)

From another point of view, there is an old saying, "if it ain't broke, don't fix it".

My comments on partitioning:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint